# import .doc and .pdf for my App

Tags: ios

I am developing an application that consists of the annotation registry.

In the form, I want the user to add files like .doc .jpg or .pdf

My question is about importing pdf and doc. Where can I import them into my app?

Can I get files from DropBox, Google Drive or iCloud?
Is there somewhere on the iPhone where my files get saved and I can get them to add to my app?

Comment: you can get it from other apps, by using share extension for the type of document you support.

Comment: See UIDocumentPickerViewController

Comment: I have never worked with sharing extensions. I will study on.

Comment: Sharing extensions has nothing to do with what you are asking about.

Comment: In a brief survey I realized that. Yes the UIDocumentPickerViewController. I'm trying to implement this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) is a proper tool for that.

Comment: Thank You. This Help me!